# Sql - Case expression with And, and Or

Tags: sql, syntax, formula

I could do some help with the following formula. It currently works, but I want to add another part to it, which I cannot figure out how to do

The current formula is:

```
,CASE
WHEN 
ABS(((t1.[RateAmount] - t1.[Amount]) / NULLIF (t1.[Amount],0) *100)) >1  
OR ABS(((t2.volume - t1.TotalVolume) / NULLIF (t1.TotalVolume, 0) *100)) >5 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END AS OverallThresholdDifference
```

However I need to add in to the volume line, if over 5 AND a difference of 2000 and my mind has gone blank

Any help here would be really appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help others understanding your question clearly.

Comment: Also would you please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using : mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another when

```
CASE
WHEN 
ABS(((t1.[RateAmount] - t1.[Amount]) / NULLIF (t1.[Amount],0) *100)) >1  
OR ABS(((t2.volume - t1.TotalVolume) / NULLIF (t1.TotalVolume, 0) *100)) >5 
THEN 1 
when
ABS(((t1.[RateAmount] - t1.[Amount]) / NULLIF (t1.[Amount],0) *100)) >5  
and ABS(((t2.volume - t1.TotalVolume) / NULLIF (t1.TotalVolume, 0) *100)) >2000 
THEN 2 

ELSE 0 
END AS OverallThresholdDifference
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE t2.volume > 5 AND OverallThresholdDifference > 2000
```

TO get the `OverallThresholdDifference` in your where clause, you will need to derive the entire query.